# Which way should I go Site Definition or Inbuilt definition with customization?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, application-pages, site-definition

I am new to Sharepoint. I need to create a totally customized site from the scratch level.
Which means there would be many pages, customized master page and etc.

I came to know that you should go for site definition project and do all the customization things in that project like web parts and if there is so much code then go for application pages too. And at last deploy it to the production server.

Till now my predecessors were creating 'Team Site' and then customize everything using custom/visual web parts and Brandings for 'Master Pages'.

So my concern is that, is it a right way to use 'Team Site' method or should I use site definition project and do all the things?

Other concern is that when there is too much customization at that time should I use application pages or create webparts and add them to the particular page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For maximum upgrade compatibility Microsoft recommends to start from Team Site and add apps or features to it. You don't have to limit yourself to content editor web parts, instead you can deploy farm solutions with feature stapling or follow the newly recommended remote provisioning methodology.

Comment: In case of lot of calculation pages...should I go for application pages or Visual webparts?

Comment: Both these building blocks will deploy to file system and get full trust. What do you mean by calculation pages? Don't implement calculations in page class, extract the logic to a library for testability.

Comment: calculation pages means....typically asp.net pages...means you hv to display grids and all those things...and one more thing what if I have 40-50 lists in project...should i use list definitions for the easy deployment purpose?

Comment: It always depends on how many copies of the same list type you plan to support and how much this type of list is unique and different from all standard templates with available CSOM customizations in mind